# Resetting iptables

Tags: iptables, postgresql

I think I've screwed up my iptables, I was trying to get postgresql to allow TCP/IP connections, not sure what I did but the iptables now look like this? How can I get them back to normal/default (allowing postgresql on port: 5432)

```
sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             bonify.archaeolabs.nl  tcp spts:1024:65535 dpt:postgresql state NEW,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  bonify.archaeolabs.nl  anywhere             tcp spt:postgresql dpts:1024:65535 state ESTABLISHED

Chain DOCKER (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Comment: `sudo iptables -F` will flush all your rules. As your default policy is ACCEPT you should then be fine.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with the following commands:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -F
sudo iptables -t mangle -F
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -X
```

`-F`: flush the iptables

`-X`: delete non-default rules

Use: `sudo iptables -S` to see what the defaults are after flushing with previous commands.

Set up the default rules:

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Setup iptables to allow postgres traffic:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 15.15.15.0/24 --dport 5432 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 5432 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Source:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-list-and-delete-iptables-firewall-rules

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/iptables-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands

Comment: sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -X

Should these be the other way around just in case you are connected over ssh as it will drop the connection before you can remove the catch all ban?

Answer (score 0):

Iptables can be resetted to the following command:

```
iptables -F
```

The option -F means "flush" and all custom rules are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to flush all the rules on all the tables and reset iptables to default:

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -X
sudo iptables -t nat -F
sudo iptables -t nat -X
sudo iptables -t mangle -F
sudo iptables -t mangle -X
sudo iptables -t raw -F
sudo iptables -t raw -X
```

Can be scripted, save this in ~/bin as say ``

```
#!/bin/bash

iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -t raw -F
iptables -t raw -X
```

Now run `sudo iptables_reset` assuming ~/bin is on your path, otherwise run `sudo /home/your_user/bin/iptable_reset`

Now save the defaults

```
sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables.default"
```

and you can restore simple as pie

```
sudo iptables-restore /etc/iptables.default
```